# python recursion i dont understand this output pls help me

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```py
def azalt(s):
    if len(s)< 1:
        return s
    else:
        print('özyinelemesürecine girerken:', s)
        azalt(s[1:])
        print('özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken:', s)

azalt('12345')
```

output :

```
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 12345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 2345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 45
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 5 #(***)
özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken: 5 
özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken: 45
özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken: 345
özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken: 2345
özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken: 12345
```

i didnt understand code after the `#(***)` (i put for highlight)

i expect output looks like this

output :

```
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 12345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 2345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 345
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 45
özyinelemesürecine girerken: 5
```

Comment: The recursive calls `azalt(s[1:])` each return eventually.  After each return, one of the "özyinelemesürecinden çıkarken" lines is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding you can add another parameter to the function (lets call it `level=`) that will increase by 1 when you call the function recursively:

```py
def azalt(s, level):
    if len(s) < 1:
        return s
    else:
        print("the string before:", s, f"{level=}")
        azalt(s[1:], level + 1)
        print("the string after:", s, f"{level=}")


azalt("12345", level=1)
```

The result is now:

```
the string before: 12345 level=1
the string before: 2345 level=2
the string before: 345 level=3
the string before: 45 level=4
the string before: 5 level=5
the string after: 5 level=5
the string after: 45 level=4
the string after: 345 level=3
the string after: 2345 level=2
the string after: 12345 level=1
```

You see that second `print()` (the one with `after`) is executed when you return from recursive function.

Comment: so the goal is to get to the end and go back to the first version? btw thanks you so much

Comment: @FurkanRyuka The point is that you call the function `azalt()` recursively but eventually you always return from this call to original function. And in the original function you print `the string after:`

Comment: still not fully understood bcs if i use with return the code does not returns again

Comment: @FurkanRyuka You can probably try https://pythontutor.com and paste your code there - you can visualize the execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with a recursion call stack, I would encourage you to look into it for fully understanding the print statements. Basically, each time `azalt` is being called recursively, it preserves the most recent line it executed and goes straight to the next call. When the next call returns, it executes the line right after it (keep in mind, it knows which line to execute because it is preserved in the stack). When it is done executing all the next steps, it returns.

call 1: azalt(12345) [prints 12345, next call, the current call on stack]

call 2: azalt(2345)  [prints 2345,  next call, the current call on stack]

call 3: azalt(345)  [prints 345,   next call, the current call on stack]

call 4: azalt(45)  [prints 45,   next call, the current call on stack]

call 5: azalt(5)  [prints 5,   next call, the current call on stack]

call 6: azalt(empty)  [return and remove from the call stack]

call 5: azalt(5) [now prints 5, return and remove from the call stack]

call 4: azalt(45) [now prints 45, return and remove from the call stack]

call 3: azalt(345) [now prints 345, return and remove from the call stack]

call 2: azalt(2345) [now prints 2345, return and remove from the call stack]

call 1: azalt(12345) [now prints 12345, return and remove from the call stack]

Hope this helps!